# Converting LatLng coordinates to point shapefile

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system

I have more than 50,000 LatLng coordinates defined under SWREFF99 1800 projection. I want to know, is it possible to convert these coordinates into a point shapefile ?
if yes, then how can I do this ?

Comment: Also see this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-convert-an-excel-file-with-x-y-columns-to-a-shapefile

Comment: I think this question is a clone then. Also my answer related to GDAL vrt driver, given from someone else, is there ;)

Comment: What the heck is a "SWREFF99 1800 projection"?  Are you perhaps referring to the [Swedish reference frame 1999](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWEREF_99)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use GDAL and the ogr2ogr command line utility, but first you need to create a VRT driver.

For example (as suggested in the GDAL doc):

(test csv)

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name
48.1,0.25,"First point"
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

This is your vrt driver:

(test.vrt)

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
        <SrcDataSource>test.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Finally use ogr2ogr to convert your test.vrt in a shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp test.vrt
```

Comment: btw, I believe that the QGIS plugin (Delimited test) is based on the ogr2ogr utility used with the vrt driver like in my sample (in other words QGIS acts as a GUI to the ogr2ogr command)

Answer (score 8):

With Qgis, you can import your coordinates with the [Delimited text plugin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-R90-CIBjA).

Comment: you beat me to it by 23 seconds and you actually found the plugin.. nice work :-)

Comment: hehe ;-) you still deserve an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ArcGIS, use the [Make XY Event Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000.htm) tool .  To persist the output of that tool to a shpfile/gdb, see the second bullet in the tool doc.

Answer (score 3):

My goto place for oddball conversions like this is the **opensource** tools at either

**QGIS**  http://www.qgis.org/

OR

**MapWindow** http://www.mapwindow.org/

My guess is there will be a "vector" plugin to do what you want at one of those two. 
I would try QGIS first because their plugins are less buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Easy done in MapInfo Professional too by create points from XY, set your coordsys and output as a shapefile.