# How to generate shapefile from Excel or CSV files?

Tags: shapefile, excel, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert an excel file with x, y columns to a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-convert-an-excel-file-with-x-y-columns-to-a-shapefile)

Probably this could be an easy question for most of the people. But I would like to know the way to generate a shapefile, if I have an input as Excel or CSV file format.

Comment: Does your source Excel/CSV have coordinates or addresses in them?

Comment: Yeah, it contains latlon too. Input can be any normal csv/excel file which should contain latlon(in my case polygon or multilinestring) and I need to get the shape file as the output. I was looking through JGrass(http://jgrasstechtips.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-shapefile.html) and trying to figure out how it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) has support for CSV files, as documented [here](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html).
In the examples section there is an example of converting a shapefile to csv which should help you get started.